# Where do temporary tables get stored in a GreenPlum database?

Tags: temp-tables, greenplum

In MS SQL Server Temporary tables are stored in [tempdb Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-2017).

Is there a similar special place in GreenPlum for temporary tables? Or is a temp table just stored in the current database & schema under which I do normal transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary tables in Greenplum are stored in the database in which they were created, but in a temporary schema which lives for the duration of the session which created the table.

i.e.

```
[gpadmin@mdw:~] $ createdb temp
[gpadmin@mdw:~] $ psql temp
temp=# create temporary table test_temp(a int) distributed by (a);
CREATE TABLE
    Time: 50.516 ms
    temp=# \d
                     List of relations
       Schema   |   Name    | Type  |  Owner  | Storage
    ------------+-----------+-------+---------+---------
     pg_temp_11 | test_temp | table | gpadmin | heap
    (1 row)

temp=# \dn
       List of schemas
        Name        |  Owner
--------------------+---------
 gp_toolkit         | gpadmin
 information_schema | gpadmin
 pg_aoseg           | gpadmin
 pg_bitmapindex     | gpadmin
 pg_catalog         | gpadmin
 pg_temp_11         | gpadmin
 pg_toast           | gpadmin
 pg_toast_temp_11   | gpadmin
 public             | gpadmin
(9 rows)

temp=#

temp=# \q

[gpadmin@mdw:~] $ psql temp
Timing is on.
psql (8.3.23)
Type "help" for help.

temp=# \d
No relations found.
temp=# \dn
       List of schemas
        Name        |  Owner
--------------------+---------
 gp_toolkit         | gpadmin
 information_schema | gpadmin
 pg_aoseg           | gpadmin
 pg_bitmapindex     | gpadmin
 pg_catalog         | gpadmin
 pg_toast           | gpadmin
 public             | gpadmin
(7 rows)

temp=#
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is priceless, because Googling did not yield for me the information you posted here. Does it always start with pg_ and contains a temp in it? I am still struggling to find the temp table I see in the source code that I inherited, despite placing a breakpoint where that temp table should still exist. I am using `psql` and `gpadmin` just like in the example you posted.